# How to validate input in my Person class

Tags: java

```
  public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public Person(String name, String email, String password) {
        setName(name);
        setEmail(email);
        setPassword(password);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name");
        }

        this.name = name;   
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        /* Validate email, throw exception */

        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        /* Validate password, throw exception */

        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

1. Best way to validate **email**, **adresses**, **passwords** (e.g. 8 characters, at least one upper-case character, one digit, ...) and throw an exception if necessary. 
   The same way I did with name ?
2. **Netbeans** complaints about using setters in the constructor ?
   If I wouldn't and just assign the value directly (this.name = name), I need to validate the input twice (one's in the constructor and in one's the setter).

Comment: In your setters the validation could be a simple regex. Use http://emailregex.com/ for email and I'm sure you can find something quick for the password. As about your setters issue, move the validation piece to a separate method that returns a bool of successful and if it is true just set this.email = email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's best to use a library to validate email addresses if you want to do it properly. Trust me it's a lot more complicated than you think - either that or just validate it has an @ and a . in it and leave it at that. Best to validate that you can send an email to it and request some verification via a link you provide. Apache commons provides a class -

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html

Password complexity validation can be as complicated as you want it and you could do this yourself fairly easily.

2. Is it Netbeans or java complaining - what warning do you get?

Comment: I'm on a different computer now, so I can't say. Something like 'setters should be final'.

Comment: You can make your setters final like this `public final void setPassword(String password) {...}`. That makes the setter impossible to override it by subclasses of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

To call setters in your constructors, you should change the scope of these functions with putting them `private` and not `public`. If you think about that, it's not a very bad idea because your checkers functions should not be callable outside of this class.